# Having a floating width:100% between two floating divs

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with 3 divs floating besides each other. The one on the left is has a constant width. The one on the right is having a dynamic width as it is the cart, and its width expands whenever something is put in the cart. The one in the middle is a search bar that is supposed to fill out the gap between to two other divs.

All of the divs are floating, and i've tried giving the middle div width:auto and width:100%, but i cant figure it out.. :(

Here is a picture of the problem:
http://ajytzler.dk/pics/width100problem.png
i want the search bar to fill out the red highlighted area.

Comment: Consider adding HTML/CSS snippets, or maybe a JSFiddle

Comment: RaulGogo is right, we really need to see some HTML+CSS before we can start helping you solve this problem (it could be any number of things, which is why we need to see the code)

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the interest :-)

Here is some access for you:
URL: [ssdbutikken.dk](http://www.ssdbutikken.dk)
User: test
pass: qwertytest